# Objective C subclassed iVar doesn't take the same pointer type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, nsindexpath

I'm getting an error I don't understand.  I subclass UICollectionViewCell as follows:

CollectionViewCell.h

```
@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *txtLabel;
```

In a view controller, I use it as follows:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UICollectionViewCell *cellOne = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The 1st call using CollectionViewCell gives a warning, the 2nd one doesn't and they are both the same class.  Alter the cell when it's selected and access the data in it.

Warning for the line with CollectionViewCell is "**Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CollectionViewCell *' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'**"

If they are both the same class with the only difference being the iVar txtLabel, why would they work differently?

I'm trying to get the cell using indexPath.  I assume there's some storage of these cells and you can access these cell using the indexPath that's passed in.

Q1. Am I correct to assume that I can get a cell by using the indexPath that's passed in?

Q2. Why would one call work and the other not when they are both the same class?

Answer (score 1):

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The method `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is defined as returning `UICollectionViewCell`. The compiler doesn't know that what is actually returned is `CollectionViewCell`.

You have to *downcast* to tell the compiler that you know what you are doing

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *) [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

this will remove the warning. It's only a warning though. It warns you about a possible mistake but the code would work correctly.